# Grease Pencil why are black strokes gray, and how to make them black for a rendered image?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

[image: gray stokes with black material]

I'm trying to make black strokes in blender, but they are not black. The material is black, the strength is at max, the opacity is 1, but the stroke is still not black.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a drawing tablet. This means that even with the strength set to 1, the darkness of the line will be based on how hard you press. To get black lines always, turn off the pressure sensitivity by clicking the icon to the right of the Strength setting (the little pencil icon with concentric circles at the tip).

This setting can mess up a lot of things in Blender, so always try turning it off if the strength behavior seems weak.

Answer (score 0):

With your Grease Pencil object selected in Object Mode, go to the *Modifier* tab in the Properties Panel and click on Add Grease Pencil Modifier at the top.

[image]

You will see a few options. One of them is **Opacity**. Choose it and select your Grease Pencil's current material under the Material dropdown, and then its Layer under the Layer dropdown.
Increase the Factor by more than its current value of 1.

[image]

The result is a completely opaque render (Before and After)

[image]

I don't know why this works, nor why it's needed in order to achieve this. But I wasn't able to get an opaque render result any other way.

Comment: this is not working it have not effect, as if i didn't add if

Comment: I don't know what else to try, but I'd suggest searching the site again, as you might find something relevant to your issue.